# Mail sending fail with attachment on IIS 7.5 with MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, iis-7.5

I am trying to send mail with attachment through hosted website on IIS7.5.

I am able to send mail without attachment but not with attachment.

I have developed web site in Asp.Net MVC4.

I am able to send mail through IIS7.5 which installed on my local machine.

```
MemoryStream objMemoryStream = new MemoryStream();
StringReader sr = new StringReader(RazorViewToString.RenderRazorViewToString(this, "~/Views/Booking/BookingFormPdf.cshtml", objBookingForm));
Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A3, 20f, 20f, 20f, 20f);
HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, objMemoryStream);               
pdfDoc.Open();
htmlparser.Parse(sr);
pdfDoc.Close();
byte[] Attachment = objMemoryStream.ToArray();
string Subject = objBookingForm.modBookingDetail.CompanyName + " Confirmation of Advertising Booking " + BookingId + ".";
string Body = "Dear " + objBookingForm.modBookingDetail.CustomerContact + "," + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + "We are pleased to confirm your advertising booking with " + objBookingForm.modBookingDetail.CompanyName + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + "Please find attached a pdf copy for your records." + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + "Regards" + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + objBookingForm.modBookingDetail.BookedBy + Environment.NewLine + objBookingForm.modBookingDetail.CompanyName;
SendEmail(objBookingForm.modBookingDetail.CustomerEmailId, Subject, Body, Attachment);
```

Comment: It will help if you expand upon how you have attempted to solve this, and the results.

Comment: I have publish same code on client machine's IIS7.5 which i have uploaded on my local machine IIS7.5